# Forcing SUMPRODUCT to ignore text values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list Table from which I'd like to extract a certain value from. The table has dates as a header and each cell in the first column indicates a different product type. Using the `SUMPRODUCT` formula as shown below instead of `HLOOKUP`, i would like to get the amount of units available for the specific product.

My issue is that I do not know in advance how many columns I will need, since I will be importing the number of units for every product every month. Therefore I will need to use entire rows instead of cell names as a range as shown in the formula below.

However, selecting row 1:5 includes the row headers in with the data and result in a `#VALUE!` error.

How can I force `SUMPRODUCT` to ignore the text values of A:A and sum the remaining cells while keeping a Rows as ranges instead of cell names?

```
         A              B                 C                 D                 E

1    Product Name   Jul-2014          Aug-2014          Sep-2014          Oct-2014

2    Product 1        1,000             1,500             3,000               750

3    Product 2        1,500             1,000              500               1,500

4    Product 3         250              1,500             1,000               800
```

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--("Product 1"=$A$2:$A$4)*--(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)=1:1)*(2:4))
```

Returns `#VALUE!`. (Should return 750, the value for Product 1 in Oct-2014.)

The formula below does return the correct result, but it requires that I know the size of the range in advance, hence no good:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--("Product 1"=$A$2:$A$4)*--(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)=B1:E1)*(B2:E4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mix your headers in with your data then you're going to make your life very complicated.

One thing you can do instead is make your ranges big enough not to worry about overflowing them. For example, extend them horizontally all the way to the last possible column in a sheet (`XFD`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--("Product 1"=$A$2:$A$4)
    *--(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)=B1:XFD1)
    *(B2:XFD4))
```

Could do something similar vertically if you don't know ahead of time how many products you will have — extend to row 1,000 or 100,000 or something you know will cover your worst case scenario (can't go higher than 1,048,756).

Another thing: you're effectively using `SUMPRODUCT` to emulate the behaviour of `INDEX` and `MATCH`. These are really the functions intended to be used for such lookup tasks. ([Forget about `VLOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP`.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel%20index%20match%20vlookup))

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$4,
    MATCH("Product 1",$A$2:$A$4,0),
    MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),$B$1:$E$1,0))
```